# TcpClient/TcpListener communication problems when not on localhost (multithreaded)

Tags: c#, multithreading, tcpclient, tcplistener

I'm working on a project where I communicate serialized commands over TCP/IP. I have it working when I'm on local host but when I run my listener on a different server, it fails randomly when trying to deserialize commands at the listeners side.
Exceptions thrown are: 'Attempting to deserialize an empty stream.' and 'End of Stream encountered before parsing was completed.' from the serializer

When I run a sequence of commands individually it works fine but when I create threads and runs several sequences simultaneously it fails.

The Listener create listeners on 4 different ports and the client runs 1 thread for each port. When one of the threads reaches the end of a sequence it terminates.

I tried to make my client singleton and also tried Mutex. But still the same problem.

Here is my client:

```
public class TcpIpCommunicator : ICommunicator, IDisposable
{
    private Dictionary<int,TcpClient> clientSockets = new Dictionary<int,TcpClient>();
    public IInverterCommand ReadAsyncCommand { set; get; }
    private static TcpIpCommunicator tcpIpCommunicator;

    private TcpIpCommunicator()
    {
    }

    public static TcpIpCommunicator GetInstance()
    {
        if(tcpIpCommunicator == null)
            tcpIpCommunicator = new TcpIpCommunicator();

        return tcpIpCommunicator;
    }

    public void Send(IInverterCommand command, int id)
    {
        var serializer = new Serializer();
        MemoryStream stream = serializer.SerializeMultipleObjects(command);
        var _bytes = stream.GetBuffer();

        var networkStream = clientSockets[id].GetStream();
        networkStream.Write(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);
        networkStream.Flush();
    }

    public IInverterCommand Read(int id)
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        byte[] buffer;
        var networkStream = clientSockets[id].GetStream();
        do
        {
            buffer = new byte[clientSockets[id].ReceiveBufferSize];
            int sizeRead = networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, sizeRead);
        } while (networkStream.DataAvailable);

        networkStream.Flush();

        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var serializer = new Serializer();
        return serializer.DeSerializeMultipleObject(memoryStream);

    }

    public void ReadAsync(object id)
    {
        ReadAsyncCommand = Read((int)id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        foreach (var tcpClient in clientSockets.Values)
        {
            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }

    public int Connect(string ip, int port)
    {
        var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        tcpClient.SendTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        tcpClient.Connect(ip, port);
        int key = findKey();
        clientSockets.Add(key, tcpClient);

        return key;
    }

    public void DestroyConnection(int id)
    {
        clientSockets[id].Close();
        clientSockets.Remove(id);
    }

    private int findKey()
    {
        int key = 0;
        while(clientSockets.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            key++;
        }

        return key;
    }
}
```

And my server side code is here:

```
public class TCPListener : IDisposable
{
    private readonly TcpListener _serverSocket;
    private NetworkStream _networkStream;
    private readonly TcpClient _clientSocket = default(TcpClient);

    public TCPListener(int port)
    {
        _serverSocket = new TcpListener(port);
        _serverSocket.Server.ReceiveTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        _serverSocket.Server.SendTimeout = int.MaxValue;
        _serverSocket.Start();
        _clientSocket = _serverSocket.AcceptTcpClient();
    }

    public void Send(IInverterCommand message)
    {
        _networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
        var serialize = new Serializer();
        var stream = serialize.SerializeMultipleObjects(message);
        var _bytes = stream.GetBuffer();

        if (_bytes.Length > _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            for (int i = 0; i < _bytes.Length; i += _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize && i + j != _bytes.Length; ++j)
                {
                    bytes[j] = _bytes[i + j];
                }

                _networkStream.Write(bytes, 0, _clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _networkStream.Write(_bytes, 0, _bytes.Length);
        }

        Thread.Sleep(50);

        _networkStream.Flush();
    }

    public IInverterCommand ReadCommand()
    {
        _networkStream = _clientSocket.GetStream();
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        do
        {
            var buffer = new byte[_clientSocket.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int sizeRead = _networkStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, sizeRead);
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        } while (_networkStream.DataAvailable);

        _networkStream.Flush();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        var serializer = new Serializer();
        return serializer.DeSerializeMultipleObject(memoryStream);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _clientSocket.Close();
        _serverSocket.Stop();
    }
}
```

Here is typically calling code at client side:

```
IInverterCommand command = new SoftwareUpdateInverterCommand();
        tcpClient.Send(command, tcpId);

        var thread = new Thread(tcpClient.ReadAsync);
        thread.Start(tcpId);

        if (!thread.Join(timeout))
        {
            thread.Abort();
            tcpClient.DestroyConnection(tcpId);
            return;
        }
```

And the server side calling code:

```
//Recieving CMD on software update
            TcpListener = new TCPListener((int)port);
            var command = TcpListener.ReadCommand();

            //Sending OK back to server
            command.Message = "OK";
            TcpListener.Send(command);
```

Comment: You tried to solve a threading issue by creating a singleton?

Comment: Can you show the calling code with different threads?

Comment: There is a lot of code if you need to see more...

Comment: The thread in the client calling code is just for doing the async read

Comment: Your TcpClient, which you are sharing between at least 2 threads is not thread safe. You have a Dictionary in there, which is not threadsafe.

Comment: In fact I don't see any attempt at thread synchronization, so potentially there's lots of places for things to get messed up. If you're reading from your Dictionary from thread A and writing to it from thread B at the same time, you're in trouble.

Comment: Each thread has it's own key to that Dictionary. So there is no shared entries. Does that make a difference?

Comment: No. The read/write from a dictionary is not thread safe. It could be interrupted anywhere. When you are in the middle of an add and then some thread tries to read from your dictionary, you'll have a collection in an undetermined state.  Bad bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you go read up on the subject of *thread synchronization* and what it means and how to use it.  Also what happens when you share things between threads that are not thread safe.

You have no thread synchronization in your code at all, yet you read and write to a Dictionary (not safe) from at least 2 different threads without any synchronization.

That alone can lead to bugs that are very hard to trace and lots of different phenomenon you rather not deal with.

You **really** need to go reading on how to do threading properly.